# How to pass parameter in usercontrol from parent form in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, parameter-passing

I have an usercontrol put on one WPF form. My WPF form has several textboxes and comboboxes.

My usercontrol has one button - Refresh, when I click on refresh button it should take values from textboxes and comboboxes and display result in panel set in usercontrol.

How can I pass these parameters in usercontrol from WPF form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take Label inside Panel, and assign TextBoxes and ComboBoxes value to label on Refresh button click event.

Answer (score 0):

User properties.

```
public string stringYouWantToGet {get{return txt.Text;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all your controls a x:Name so you can access them in the view (not using "form" for WPF...) and implement the click event handler in the view as well. In the event handler pass the desired values to your User Control.